# service stack wildcard path with swagger

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I'm using ServiceStack and have the route like this:

```
[Route("/hello/{Name*}")]
```

So anything like `/hello/some/parameters` should be handled.
Swagger use the following url: `/hello/{Name*}` and no matter what value I provide for Name parameter I get the following message when I hit "Try it out button":
A potentially dangerous client value Request.Path retrieved from the client(*).

Note, I'm using the following ApiMember attribute:

`[ApiMember(Name = "Params", DataType = "string", ParameterType = "path" , IsRequired = true)]`

and still any text I input is overriden with * and I have the error as above.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the error is occurring because the Swagger call is using the default value of {Name*} in the path/request. (*) is not allowed in the path of the URL. 
By using the correct attributes in your ServiceStack class, you should be able to get a text box to enter your own value within the Swagger UI.

Something like below should get the text box to appear. See https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/SwaggerHelloWorld for examples.

```
public class Hello {
  [ApiMember(Name=”Name*”, Description = “Name Description”, ParameterType = “path”, DataType = “string”, IsRequired = true)] 
   public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Initially I did the same thing, yes, it doesn't work. I will update the question so that it's clear.

Comment: Try adding Name="Name*" in the ApiMember attribute. I updated my answer to reflect this change as well.